# pandas dataframe take rows before certain indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing, data-munging

I have a dataframe and a list of indexes, and I want to get a new dataframe such that for each index (from the given last), I will take the all the preceding  rows that matches in the value of the given column at the index.

```
      C1 C2 C3
0     1  2  A
1     3  4  A
2     5  4  A
3     7  5  B
4     9  7  C
5     2  3  D
6     1  1  D
```

The column c3 the indexes (row numbers) 2, 4 , 5 my new dataframe will be:

```
     C1 C2 C3
0     1  2  A
1     3  4  A
2     5  4  A
4     9  7  C
5     2  3  D
```

Explanation:

For index 2, rows 0,1,2 were selected because C3 equals in all of them.

For index 4, no preceding row is valid.

And for index 5 also no preceding row is valid, and row 6 is irrelevant because it is not preceding.
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: @SaiKumar I editted, is it better now? please see the example

Comment: can you tell me why is your desired output only have `0,1,2,4,5` rows?

Comment: @SaiKumar added to the post, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make conditions to filter data,if you want just preceding rows match to condition.

```
ind= 2
col ='C3'
# ".loc[np.arange(ind+1)]" creates indexes till preceding row, so rest of matching conditions can be ignored 
df.loc[df.loc[ind][col] == df[col]].loc[np.arange(ind+1)].dropna()
```

Out:

```
   C1   C2  C3
0   1   2   A
1   3   4   A
2   5   4   A
```

appying on other column

```
ind= 2
col ='C2'
df.loc[df.loc[ind][col] == df[col]].loc[np.arange(ind+1)].dropna()
```

Out:

```
   C1   C2  C3
1   3.0 4.0 A
2   5.0 4.0 A
```

Comment: can you please explain the .loc[np.arange(ind+1)]?

Comment: first the condition will select all matching conditions in df, iloc  creates indexes prior to ind row, so rest of matching conditions can be ignored :-) @oren_isp